# HTTPPUT check if update was successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Please help. I am trying to do a put. However, even if I update a record using an ID that does not exist it still give me a "Success". How do I check if no records were updated then return BadReques()?

```
 [HttpPut]

    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<CaseInformation>>> UpdateCaseInformation(UpdateCaseInformation UpdateCaseInfo)
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("SQlServer"));



        var caseInfo = await connection.ExecuteAsync("dbo.UpdateCaseInformationByIDSP", UpdateCaseInfo, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        return Ok();
```

Comment: What do you want to return once Id not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do a put. However, even if I update a record using an
> ID that does not exist it still give me a "Success"

Actually, you are getting the expected output because you are not checking the ID you are passing to update your record whether it is exist at all. Another issue within your code were, no additional code block for comparing the condition once it got failed.

Thus, you would need to introduce an additional block to check if the Id exist only then you would move to your update statement block otherwise execution need to stopped and return your status of 404 or bad reqeust, anything you want.

**Solution:**

```
        [HttpPut]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<CaseInformation>>> UpdateCaseInformation(UpdateCaseInformation UpdateCaseInfo)
        {
            //First Check if the case exist
            var isCaseExist = _appDbContext.YourCaseTable.Where(check => check.CaseId== UpdateCaseInfo.CaseId || check.CaseCode== UpdateCaseInfo.Code).FirstOrDefault();
            if (isCaseExist == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            // Execute Update Operation
            //using var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("SQlServer"));

            //var caseInfo = await connection.ExecuteAsync("dbo.UpdateCaseInformationByIDSP", UpdateCaseInfo, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);


            //Return status what you want
            var updateMessage = "Case has been updated";
            return Ok(updateMessage);
        }
```

**Note:** The key point is first [execute a read operation like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples) before moving to update operation. Its the most common practice for [WEB API](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part6/).

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**  In my sample I am checking using entityframework if the data exist. You can do that using [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) as per your scenario by writing simple  [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples). Then, you can keep your existing code.